# Trinomial Coefficients in Python

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Trying to figure out a dynamic programming way to return the trinomial coefficients.

I'm confused on how to get the value of the rows. I was able to set up the structure of the rows. The number of values in the row is the row number + 2. I can't figure out the code for the real values, so I just have placeholder values.

I know the middle value in the row is the sum of the row above, ignoring the 1s on the side. I know some formula like you go up 1, and diagonal 1 and add those values to get the value underneath, but I don't how to put that into code.

```py
def Trinomial_Triangle(Number_of_Rows):
    Triangle = [[1]]
    Length_of_Row = 1

    for Outer_Index in range(Number_of_Rows - 1):

        Temporary_Array = [0] + Triangle[Outer_Index] + [0]
        print("Temporary Array", Temporary_Array)
        Length_of_Row += 2
        Values_in_Row = []

        for First_Inner_Index in range(Length_of_Row):

            Value = Triangle[Outer_Index][0]

            Values_in_Row.append(Value)
        Triangle.append(Values_in_Row)
    return Triangle


print(Trinomial_Triangle(5))
```

[image: Trinomial Coefficients]

Comment: You could use a simple loop or recursion. The use of dynamic programming, an optimisation technique, would be be out-of-place here. What makes you think the use of DP would be desireable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do something like that:

```
def trinomial_triangle(num_of_rows):
    triangle = [[1]]
    for outer_idx in range(num_of_rows):
        prev_row = [0, 0] + triangle[outer_idx] + [0, 0]
        triangle.append([])
        for idx in range(1, len(prev_row) - 1):
            triangle[-1].append(sum(prev_row[idx - 1: idx + 2]))
    return triangle

print(trinomial_triangle(5))
```

##### Output:

```
[[1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3, 2, 1], [1, 3, 6, 7, 6, 3, 1], [1, 4, 10, 16, 19, 16, 10, 4, 1], [1, 5, 15, 30, 45, 51, 45, 30, 15, 5, 1]]
```

---

I padded the last row with 4 zeros - two of each side:

- One to create the length of the new row
- One for padding for the sum of the 3 values above (to avoid extra steps for the first and last values)

Then I summed the 3 values from the prev row (one before and one after the current index) and appended it to the last list in `triangle`.

> The trinomial triangle is a variation of Pascal’s triangle. The difference between the two is that an entry in the trinomial triangle is the sum of the three (rather than the two in Pascal’s triangle) entries above it

You can read more about *trinomial triange* and how to create it in **[this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trinomial-triangle/)** article

Answer (score 1):

An array describing a trinomial triangle with `nrows` rows is desired. Note that row `i` (base 0) of that array is seen to contain `2*i+1` elements.

I will begin with a very simple algorithm.

**Simple algorithm**

After reading each of the following four steps you might find it helpful to examine the calculations performed for that step in an example I've provided below.

*Step 1*

Create an array `arr` having `nrows` elements (rows), each element being an array of `2*nrows+1` zeroes.

The element of `arr` at index `i` (base 0) is denoted `arr[i]`. The element of `arr[i]` at index `j` (base 0) is therefore `arr[i][j]`.

*Step 2*

Change `arr[0][nrows]` to `1`.

*Step 3*

Loop over `i = 1..nrows-1`. For each `i` and for each `j = 1..2*nrows-1`, compute

```
arr[i][j] = arr[i-1][j-1] + arr[i-1][j] + arr[i-1][j+1]
```

*Step 4*

Loop over `i = 1..nrows-1`. For each `i` and each `j = 0..2*nrows-1` remove element `arr[i][j]` from `arr[i]` if `arr[i][j] = 0`. Return `arr`.

**Example**

Suppose `nrows = 5`.

*Step 1*

Note `2*nrows+1 = 11`. `arr` equals the following.

```
[
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
]
```

*Step 2*

Change `arr[0][5]` to `1`. `arr` now equals the following.

```
[
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
]
```

*Step 3*

`arr` now equals the following.

```
[
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  2,  1,  0,  0,  0 ],
  [ 0,  0,  1,  3,  6,  7,  6,  3,  1,  0,  0 ],
  [ 0,  1,  4, 10, 16, 19, 16, 10,  4,  1,  0 ]
]
```

*Step 4*

`arr` now equals the following.

```
[
  [ 1 ],
  [ 1,  1,  1],
  [ 1,  2,  3,  2,  1],
  [ 1,  3,  6,  7,  6,  3,  1],
  [ 1,  4, 10, 16, 19, 16, 10,  4,  1]
]
```

**Improving efficiency**

There are several things that could be done to improve time and space efficiency, but there is no point in doing that unless `nrows` could be sufficiently large. As is, the algorithm is simple and the code easy to follow, and unit tests are straightforward.

If greater efficiency is desired the simplest improvement is in Step 3, by changing

"For each `i` and for each `j = 1..2*nrows-1`"

to

"For each `i` and for each `j = nrows-i..nrows+i`

For example, when `nrows = 5` and `i = 3` we need only consider `j` ranging from `2` to `8`, which we see is the case in the example above.

Another simple improvement could be done in Step 4. Rather than removing elements equal to zero, we could perform the following pseudo-code (Ruby, actually) operation (where `m..n` denotes a range of integers):

```
(0..nrows-1).map { |i| arr[i][nrows-i..nrows+i] }
```

We could of course begin with `arr =[[1]]` and then add elements (rows) in the obvious way but it's messier, harder to follow and test and in the end may not significantly improve time efficiency, and space efficiency may not be an issue.